# Search value in all tables content - oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to search a specific word **in all tables content**.
I mean in all column contents of all tables.

I don't mean in all tables names or all column names.

Thanks.

Comment: @xQbert in that searching in column_name. Am i wrong ?

Comment: The dynamic portion of Dave Costa's answer is searching all tables all columns for a specific value.  The top most is just searching for a table or column name in the database, not what you want.

Comment: Yes. I need to search in all column contents. But how :)

Comment: Take a close look at the dynamic SQL in Dave Costa's answer starting `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 100000` and ending `/`  What it does is iterate though all the system table/columns and generate SQL statements  searching for desired content.  It executes each statement and outputs the table/column name if the content is found.  Again, his answer has what you  are after if you take the time to understand it.